# Is it possible to build spark code on fly and execute?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to create a generic function to read a csv file using databriks CSV READER.But the option's are not mandatory it can differ based on the my input json configuration file.

**Example1 :**

```
 "ReaderOption":{

                    "delimiter":";",
                    "header":"true",
                    "inferSchema":"true",
                    "schema":"""some custome schema.."""
            },
```

**Example2:**

```
   "ReaderOption":{

                        "delimiter":";",
                        "schema":"""some custome schema.."""
                },
```

Is it possible to construct options or the entire read statement in runtime and run in spark ?

like below,

```
  def readCsvWithOptions(): DataFrame=
{

  val options:Map[String,String]= Map("inferSchema"->"true")
  val readDF = jobContext.spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option(options)
  .load(inputPath)
  readDF
}
```

Comment: .options(options) helps to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

def readCsvWithOptions(): DataFrame=
{

val options:Map[String,String]= Map("inferSchema"->"true")
  val readDF = jobContext.spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .options(options)
  .load(inputPath)
  readDF
}

There is an options which takes key, value pair.